# How to convert records to dictionary as fast as possible

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

my 3milions of keys/values looks like this

```
(key1, key2, key3, key4, key5)

(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
```

and each key and value can be a 1 to 1 match.

I want to make dictionary like this

`{(key1, key2, ... ) : (value1, value2, ...), (key6, key7, ...) : (value6, value7, ...), ...}`

Any advise?

Comment: How many keys and values you want to make per each iteration?

Comment: So group 5 by 5 ?

Comment: Actually, it is 5 by 7

Comment: @mhhabib About 3million for total,

Answer (score 1):

You may build chunks for the keys and the values, then use `dict(zip(ks,vs))` and it'll pair them and build the key/value correspondance in a dict

```
keys = tuple(f'k{i}' for i in range(13))
values = tuple(f'v{i}' for i in range(13))

chunk_size = 2
result = dict(zip(
    (keys[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(keys), chunk_size)),
    (values[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(keys), chunk_size)),
))
# {('k0', 'k1'): ('v0', 'v1'), ('k2', 'k3'): ('v2', 'v3'), ('k4', 'k5'): ('v4', 'v5'), ('k6', 'k7'): ('v6', 'v7'), ('k8', 'k9'): ('v8', 'v9'), ('k10', 'k11'): ('v10', 'v11'), ('k12',): ('v12',)}


chunk_size = 5
# {('k0', 'k1', 'k2', 'k3', 'k4'): ('v0', 'v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4'), ('k5', 'k6', 'k7', 'k8', 'k9'): ('v5', 'v6', 'v7', 'v8', 'v9'), ('k10', 'k11', 'k12'): ('v10', 'v11', 'v12')}
```